# 14.04 always asks for password for a network drive (sftp)

Tags: 14.04, password, sftp, network-drive

I just upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04.

When I connect to a SFTP site it always (after rebooting) prompt me for username and password, even though I click the option to store them forever (it worked well on 12.04). Thanks.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. Could you add more in-detail such as how are you connecting to the site using SFTP protocol? is it using any type of application or have you done any customized modification... etc???

Comment: Hi,I am using nautilus, File -> connect to server, the sftp://sftp.itd.umich.edu  It is default, no tweak or custom stuff.
I am then prompted for user & pass, presenting 3 options for password storage: forget (single-use); save for this session and save permanently. But after reboot/restart/logout, this same prompt does appear.

Comment: Those keyrings are stored on `~/.gnome2/keyrings` but not human readable. Nevertheless, Ubuntu's default password manager **Seahorse** should let you access it. Just search for seahorse on Dash home and you'll find the password manager. I'm not too sure but you can may be try deleting that specific entry, then reboot & try re-adding as a fresh entry. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Do you connect to the server using your bookmarks?
In this case the issue can be resolved by adding the user name to the URL in the "Edit Bookmarks" dialog of nautilus (sftp://user@host.com instead of sftp://host.com)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its faulty ipv6 hardware?

Try to connect to your server using a terminal 
 `$ ssh -vvv  -l your_user_name your_server`

if its stopping at resolving the ipv6 ctrl-c and try

`$ ssh -vvv -4 -l your_user_name your_server`

binding to ipv4 only. If this work, we need to find a way to tell to use ipv4 only to nautilus.